# Order of AuthorizationFilter applied to a controller/method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

if I have two custom implementation of IAuthorizationFilter, and both of them applied to a method in a controller, how do we determine which filter is executed first?

e.g.

Declaration:

```
public class MyAuthenticationFilter : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
public class MyAuthorisationFilter : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
```

Applied:

```
    [MyAuthorisationFilter(AllowedRoles = "Admin")]
    [MyAuthenticationFilter()]
    public class UsersController : Controller
{
...
}
```

Through experiments it seems that the Authenication one is executed first just because it is placed nearer to the controller declaration... Can we specify the order or is it a default behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Order property:

```
[MyAuthenticationFilter(Order=1)]
[MyAuthorisationFilter(AllowedRoles = "Admin",Order=2)]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
...
}
```

Comment: Interesting! Order is the way to order!

I still wonder why the default order is the one below executed first...

Comment: Unfortunately The execution order cannot be determined unless you use the Order attribute. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609.aspx